# Play song from iPod library, having only its title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, media-player

I need to start playing a song (which is in the iPod library) in another iOS App using the name of the song.

I've studied some of the MediaPlayer framework, but didn't find anything useful.
I know this can be done, as a couple of apps in the App Store do it, such as SoundHound, which lets you play a certain song you've discovered if you have it in your iPod library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/

EDIT:

you can try this to reach songs:

```
#pragma mark - Media Picker

- (IBAction)showMediaPicker:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny];

    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select songs to play";

    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
    [mediaPicker release];
}

- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{
    if (mediaItemCollection) {

        [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
        [musicPlayer play];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}


- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to play a song with a specific title, without requiring the user to select the song manually with the Media Picker, you might want to try a Media Player Query using the song title.

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *titlePredicate =
[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:searchText
                             forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
                             comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];

NSSet *predicates = [NSSet setWithObjects: titlePredicate, nil];

MPMediaQuery *songsQuery =  [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates: predicates];

NSLog(@"%@", [songsQuery items]);
```

There is are good code examples and more discussion on queries at [MPMediaQuery search for Artists, Albums, and Songs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352767/mpmediaquery-search-for-artists-albums-and-songs)