# MPMediaQuery not returning any results when filtered with MPMediaPropertyPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on building an iOS music player and for some reason, whenever I try and pull in all of the songs in a given album to display them in a table view my query comes up empty. I've tried running a query for all songs on the device, and it works perfectly fine, but for some reason when I try and filter it with a Media Predicate nothing is returned:

```
// Pull the currently playing song's album
MPMediaItem *currentSong = [self.store currentlyPlayingSong];
NSString *album = [currentSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];

// Begin filtering by album title
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:album forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo];
NSSet *albumSet = [NSSet setWithObject:albumPredicate];

MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:albumSet];
NSArray *albumSongs = [albumQuery items];
    NSLog(@"Album Songs: %@", [albumQuery items]);
```

Basically, I want to pull the album title from the currently playing song and then use that as the filter. I've been trying to use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352767/mpmediaquery-search-for-artists-albums-and-songs) as a guide, but I can't seem to get any combination of the proposed solutions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it...I stupidly enough had made a typo I hadn't noticed. I was pulling in the album name, but filtering by Artist...