# Play Song using MPMediaItemPropertyTitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, mpmediaitem

I get Song title in TableView using this code:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];

    for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {

        NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songTitleArray addObject:songTitle];
    }
```

Now I want to play that song inside tableView I added Two button play and Stop how to play using Title in same ViewController.

Comment: Hope this will helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352767/mpmediaquery-search-for-artists-albums-and-songs

Comment: @Amanpreet At this link it has been stated that How to get Title of Song. i have already fetched Title. Now want to play.

Answer (score 0):

To play song you can do something like :

```
MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:arrayOfMediaItems];
MPMediaItem *item = [collection representativeItem];

[controller setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
[controller setNowPlayingItem:item];

[controller prepareToPlay];
[controller play];
```

You can also use `AVPlayer` to play song, after picking it through `MPMediaPickerController` :

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
   didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {


    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    // Play the item using MPMusicPlayer

    MPMusicPlayerController* appMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    [appMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
    [appMusicPlayer play];


    // Play the item using AVPlayer

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player play];  

}
```

Comment: what to write in arrayOfMediaItems. i got the Title of Song from My snippets. is there is any way to play song based on my Song Title. My array having only Song Title.

Comment: i don't want Present MPMediaPickerController. so this delegates method  didPickMediaItems having no use

Comment: Why don't you directly play "song", instead of getting its title and saving in "songTitleArray". Play it directly.

Comment: How? User will get idea about Which Song it is. it's in My tableview and want to play from that ViewController not from MPMediaPickerController

Comment: You can display its name in the tableview like, but to play the song you will need this "MPMediaItem", you can not play with string only

Comment: Ok So i have that Title Now when one click on certain title then how will it play. as you have written code in didPickMediaItems that is Delegate. in my case this will be no there

Comment: Instead of making an array of "songTitles", you can show this title from "itemsFromGenericQuery" array, like : "[itemsFromGenericQuery.objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)"  and to play use "[controller setNowPlayingItem:itemsFromGenericQuery.objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; [controller prepareToPlay]; [controller play];"